# Grouping hosts in SSH Config

Tags: ssh

Can I configure the hosts in my SSH config by groups? For example, I'd like to set a single same user to be used for one group of hosts and another one for another group of hosts.

If it's not possible out of the box, I guess there might be tools that can write or manage your ssh_config through a config file format with some richer options?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You should take a look at `man 5 ssh_config` for all the details on this, but yes, you can do that by doing this in your ~/ssh_config:

```
Host srv1 srv2 srv3
    User jorn

Host srv4 srv5 srv6
    User jornv

Host *.company.com
    User jornw
```

The * can also be used to do string matching for hosts

Comment: Also you can use patterns, like *.company.com. This might be shorter if you have a lot of similar servers around.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a template system like [Jinja2](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/) to generate ssh ~/.ssh/config. I use such system to merge multiple ssh configs from multiple envs.

Comment: An example of how this is achieved would be helpful.