# How to configure ssh client for different host groups?

Tags: linux, ssh

Is there a way to edit my ssh config to apply config based on groups of hosts?

Here my imaginary ~/.ssh/config

```
HostGroup workhosts
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/workkey
  User workuser

HostGroup projectA
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/projkey
  User projuser

HostGroup homeVM
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/vmkey
  User hobbyuser

# Some default for fall back
HostGroup noGroup
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/defaultkey
  User defaultuser
  IdentitiesOnly yes
```

Ideally all host groups would have different destinct ip adresses. But that is not the case, since both at home and at work the IPs are within 192.168.0.0/16. Well at least some of them, which stops me from grouping by IP-adresses.

There are many hosts, so having identical config for each and every host is not practical (impossible based on IPs that can overlap but possible with FQDN).

Any ideas if that kind of config is possible?

Comment: May be duplicate of this https://superuser.com/a/349018/673426 ? You can't use named groups, but you can specify multiple names or wildcards like `Host work1 work2 *.work.com`  and settings below will apply to that list

Comment: hmm this seems quite feasable for a handful hosts. But can I really put 40 hostnames with fqdns in there? I guess I'll try, thanks. Too bad named groups are not possible.

Comment: Yes, current openssh reads up to 4096 byte long lines, so it should be fine: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45501322/7411885